# Powershell script to merge common rows of a text file based on first column

Tags: powershell

guys

I've got this text file:

```
A a
B b
C c
C d
C e
C f
```

and wanted to get this as result:

```
A: a
B: b
C: c, d, e, f
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

In bash, I had something like this:

```
awk -i inplace '$3 != prev {if (NR != 1) print prev; prev=$3; delete a};
!($1 in a){a[$1]++; printf "%s ", $1};
!($2 in a){a[$2]++; printf "%s ", $2}; 
END {print prev}' $file
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is undoubtedly slower than raw text processing, but showcases PowerShell's OO capabilities:

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -header colA, colB $file |
  Group-Object colA | 
  ForEach-Object { '{0}: {1}' -f $_.Name, ($_.Group.colB -join ', ') }
```

If you want to write the results back to the input file, enclose the `Import-Csv` call in `(...)` and append `| Set-Content $file` to the pipeline (character-encoding caveats apply).